# Trigger to insert data row into new table when old table is updated

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

Want to insert only the updated row into the log table, but got error for the following trigger block :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER system_notification_audit
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE on ncr_system_notification
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  insert into ncr_system_notification_log
  values
    (:NEW.ID,
     :NEW.NAME,
     :NEW.Description,
     :NEW.PREFERENCE,
     :NEW.FREQUENCY,
     :NEW.IS_HIGH,
     :NEW.IS_REQUIRED,
     :NEW.UPDATED_BY,
     :NEW.UPDATED_DATE) 
   where :OLD.IS_REQUIRED <> :NEW.IS_REQUIRED;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to do this is with a PL/SQL conditional:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER system_notification_audit
 AFTER 
      INSERT OR 
      UPDATE 
on ncr_system_notification
FOR EACH ROW
begin

    if :OLD.IS_REQUIRED <> :NEW.IS_REQUIRED then
        insert into ncr_system_notification_log
        VALUES (:NEW.ID , :NEW.NAME, :NEW.Description, :NEW.PREFERENCE, :NEW.FREQUENCY, :NEW.IS_HIGH, :NEW.IS_REQUIRED, :NEW.UPDATED_BY, :NEW.UPDATED_DATE) ;     
    end if ;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an `insert` with a `select` statement :

```
insert into ncr_system_notification_log 
select :NEW.ID , :NEW.NAME, :NEW.Description, :NEW.PREFERENCE, :NEW.FREQUENCY, 
       :NEW.IS_HIGH, :NEW.IS_REQUIRED, :NEW.UPDATED_BY, :NEW.UPDATED_DATE
  from dual
 where :OLD.IS_REQUIRED <> :NEW.IS_REQUIRED;
```

Assume `IS_REQUIRED` a *nullable non-negative integer* column, then a *negative value* for `nvl` function's second argument might be assumed a negative integer such as -1 in the inequality as :

```
where nvl(:OLD.IS_REQUIRED,-1) <> nvl(:NEW.IS_REQUIRED,-1)
```

Comment: @APC 's solution below is better than this one, since it doesn't require context switch when :old.is_required = :new.is_required, i believe.

Comment: @piezol In both cases processing are done in the same manner I think.

Comment: @PardeepKumar you're welcome. Is `IS_REQUIRED` column nullable ..?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Are you sure?
APC's solution doesn't do insert at all - so it does not require context switch to sql engine.

Comment: @piezol ok, you mean the performance point of view(indeed a negligible impact), but the inserted data doesn't differ.